# Let $f(x)=x\sin{(\pi x)}$. Spivak's solution manual seems to imply $f'(0)$ does not exist for this function. Why?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The following is a problem from Ch. 23 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> Let $f$ be a continuous function on an interval around $0$, and let
> $a_n=f(1/n)$ (for large enough $n$).
>
> 6(d) Suppose $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ converges. Must $f'(0)$
> exist?

The answer I came up with is simply a function that has a kink at $f(0)=0$ (ie, not differentiable there), but which for non-negative $x$ is such that $a_n=f(1/n)$ and $\{a_n\}$ is summable.

For example, $f(x)=x^2$ for $x\geq 0$, and $f(x)=-x$ for $x<0$.

Then, $f(0)=0$, $f$ is continuous there, and $f'(0)$ does not exist, but $\{a_n\}=\{1/n^2\}$ is summable.

Is this an adequate counterexample to the idea that $f'(0)$ must exist if $\sum a_n$ converges?

Then I looked at the solution manual and it says

> No. Consider $f(x)=x\sin\{(\pi x)\}$, $f(0)=0$.

But isn't this function differentiable at $0$?

Comment: Please check that my edit preserves the intent, and compare with the question title.

Comment: Please explain how the series relates to $f$, e.g. by quoting the relevant part of the exercise.

Comment: I forgot to put in the beginning of the problem statement. It is fixed now.

Comment: IT must be a typo in your booklet. I think the meant to write $x\sin(\pi/(x))$ for then $f(1/n)=0$

Comment: $\frac{d}{dx}(x \sin(π x)) = \sin(π x) + π x \cos(π x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the question is hinting at a comparison between continuous and discrete limits.

The answer is likely a typo that intended $f(x)= x\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$

Here $f(\frac{1}{n})=0$ for all $n$, yet $f$ is not differentiable at 0.

Comment: @jordi, thanks!